# Change from UIWebView to WKWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, uistoryboard

**I'm trying to change my `UIWebView` to `WKWebView`**.

My `WebPageViewController` just looks this simple on Storyboards:
[image]

I'd like to implement the Reading View and back buttons and estimated progress, but I'm not sure if I'm even getting this first step right.

If the first step is right though, and I'm wanting to set up the configuration, am I adding something like this to my code?:
    `WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];`

And would I need to add a `@property (strong, nonatomic) WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration;` to get it all working?

Here's my code changes so far if needed:

**WebPageViewController.m UIWebView**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringWeb];

    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}
```

**WebViewController.m WKWebView**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKWebView *webView;

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringWeb];

[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}
```

Comment: I'm not so sure about adding the new web view as a subview to the old one. Why not just remove it from the view hierarchy and then add your new one?

Comment: Makes sense, let me try that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instantiate and set the `WKWebViewConfiguration` on the web view in `viewDidLoad` without storing it in a property.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
  // ...
  self.webView.configuration = configuration;
}
```

Comment: The webView.configuration property is read only. Can only be set when initialising: webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) configuration:webViewConfig];

Comment: The webView.configuration property is read only, can you please provide another solution.

Comment: This answer no longer applies as the `configuration` property is read only. Any other suggestions?